# Why is the sentence "Statistics 'is' often misleading" incorrect?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Why is the sentence "*Statistics **is** often misleading*" incorrect?

I know that statistics can be singular but also plural. Should I use singular in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Statistics*, when used as a singular noun, refers to a field of study:

> **[Statistics](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/statistics?q=statistics)**
>
> *noun*
>
> *[treated as singular]*
>
> the practice or science of collecting and analysing numerical data in large quantities, especially for the purpose of inferring proportions in a whole from those in a representative sample.

It would be incorrect to say that an entire field of study can be misleading. That would be like saying that Calculus is misleading, or Geology or something.

*Statistics* can also be used as the plural form of *statistic*. Any *statistic* could be misleading if presented in the right (wrong) way. Therefore, the correct form of the sentence is

> *Statistics **are** often misleading*

Comment: ...meaning the sentence is correct grammatically, but wrong, unless you're strongly opinionated against the whole science.

Comment: And I'd argue from the large amount of statistical innumeracy easily found in the press, that the science of statistics as a whole is easily misunderstood by those that don't practice it. That could be boldly stated for emphasis by saying "Statistics is often misleading." It would be an over-generalization, certainly, and as such is likely to itself be misleading. And it also seems like an awkward construction.